# Mysql query taking 20 minutes only for 11000 records. how to optimize below mysql query select query in where clause with not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACA.Application_No, AC.FirstName,AC.Id,AC.LastName,AC.MobileNo,CL.leadId
        FROM ABSLI_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION APT
             INNER JOIN ABSLI_CUSTOMER_APPLICATION ACA ON ACA.Policy_No=APT.policyId
             INNER JOIN ABSLI_CUSTOMER AC ON AC.Id=ACA.CustomerId
             LEFT JOIN ABSLI_CUSTOMER_LEAD CL ON CL.policyId = ACA.Policy_No
             INNER JOIN ABSLI_Policy_Status_Tracking pst ON pst.policyId = APT.policyId
        WHERE APT.paymentStatus='Y'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ABSLI_SERVICE_STATUS WHERE PolicyNo=APT.policyId AND NAME = 'APEX_Validate')
             AND ACA.Application_No NOT IN (SELECT RT.ApplicationNumber FROM ABSLI_REFUND_TRANSACTION RT WHERE RT.Status != 'Retain')
        ORDER BY pst.updatedDate DESC;
```

Comment: "Why is my query slow" questions should include the query plan if we are to offer any meaningful advice

Comment: Do you have an index on `ABSLI_REFUND_TRANSACTION.ApplicationNumber` column?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yes.

Comment: ..Also the DISTINCT is spanning multiple tables which never can be optimized as it would always require a temp table the process and possible a sort the get the correct results, the best you can optimize is the ON , WHERE and ORDER BY clauses..

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Correlated subqueries can be costly on larger datasets, you might want to try converting

```
...
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ABSLI_SERVICE_STATUS WHERE PolicyNo=APT.policyId AND NAME = 'APEX_Validate')
...
```

to something like

```
...
LEFT JOIN ABSLI_SERVICE_STATUS AS ss ON APT.policyId = ss.PolicyNo AND ss.NAME = 'APEX_Validate'
...
AND ss.NAME IS NULL
```

Normally, I'd suggest an "id" field from `ss` for the IS NULL check, but `NAME` obviously exists (from the query you have) and cannot be 'APEX_Validate' and NULL at the same time. Also, if there is a compound index on `PolicyNo, Name` that index can probably be used without accessing the table itself.)

Comment: Ditto for the `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have an index on `ABSLI_REFUND_TRANSACTION.ApplicationNumber` column, you can try to use `NOT EXISTS` also for the second subquery instead of `NOT IN`. This way, you benefit this index for that subquery, and usually `NOT IN` might be problematic for large set of data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACA.Application_No, AC.FirstName, AC.Id, AC.LastName, AC.MobileNo, CL.leadId
  FROM ABSLI_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION APT
 INNER JOIN ABSLI_CUSTOMER_APPLICATION ACA
    ON ACA.Policy_No = APT.policyId
 INNER JOIN ABSLI_CUSTOMER AC
    ON AC.Id = ACA.CustomerId
  LEFT JOIN ABSLI_CUSTOMER_LEAD CL
    ON CL.policyId = ACA.Policy_No
 INNER JOIN ABSLI_Policy_Status_Tracking pst
    ON pst.policyId = APT.policyId
 WHERE APT.paymentStatus = 'Y'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM ABSLI_SERVICE_STATUS
                    WHERE PolicyNo = APT.policyId
                      AND NAME = 'APEX_Validate')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM ABSLI_REFUND_TRANSACTION RT
                    WHERE RT.Status != 'Retain'
                      AND RT.ApplicationNumber = ACA.Application_No)
 ORDER BY pst.updatedDate DESC;
```

But without knowing the execution plan, hard to tell more about performance.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, I take them to `GROUP BY` list

Comment: never mind mine comment iam drinking beer now,i didn't notice.. But same counts with GROUP BY , as the GROUP BY spans multiple tables it would always require a temp table to process and possible a sort to get the correct results

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm not sure about that, you maybe right. In Oracle, I witnessed GROUP BY was giving performance than DISTINCT, perhaps it might be experienced by OP :) Without knowing explain plan ... bla bla bla ....

Comment: *"In Oracle, I witnessed GROUP BY was giving performance than DISTINCT,"* in MySQL DISTINCT and GROUP BY are more or less the same see manual [DISTINCT Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Comment: nice @RaymondNijland, then we don't need to consider such a situation, thanks.